# This Serverless Function has timed out in Next app

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, getserversideprops

I'm using getServerSideProps' to get a parameter in the URL, no big deal, but when I upload my application to Vercel (Hobby plan) I have the following problem

> This Serverless Function has timed out.
> Your connection is working correctly.
> Vercel is working correctly.

> 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT ID: > gru1::5g5x4-1687230420091-471e7398e9e4

> If you are a visitor, contact the website owner or try again later.
> If you are the owner, learn how to fix the error and check the logs.

I tested the Pro plan, and when using vercel.json the problem is "solved"

```
{
   "framework": "nextjs",
   "functions": {
     "src/pages/[nickName]": {
       "memory": 3008,
       "maxDuration": 20
     }
   }
}
```

what's the best way?

Comment: So, on the hobby plan, max execution is 10 seconds, you're hitting this limit. Whatever you've got going on in your 'setServerSideProps', it's is doing a lot of heavy lifting, either that or it's hitting a problem that's slowing it down. What's in there?

Comment: @JamesWilliam 

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      nickName: query.nickName
    }
  };
};

Comment: I know it's a simple operation, but why are you having all this processing for this?